# Cannot reach docker container port for gitlab ssh

Tags: docker, networking, gitlab

I have setup a gitlab server with the gitlab ce docker container. This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  web:
    image: 'gitlab/gitlab-ee:latest'
    restart: always
    hostname: '<URL>'
    environment:
      GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG: |
        external_url '<URL>'
        nginx['listen_port'] = 80
        nginx['listen_https'] = false
        gitlab_rails['gitlab_shell_ssh_port'] = 2224
    ports:
      - '8929:80'
      - '2224:22'
    volumes:
      - '/var/www/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab'
      - '/var/www/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab'
      - '/var/www/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab'
```

Netstat -tnlp | grep 2224:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::2224                 :::*                    LISTEN      32627/docker-proxy
```

I can reach the container with `ssh git@localhost -p 2224` from the docker host but not from the internet on the public ip address.

I have added a rule to ufw and also tried to disable it but it didn't help.
The nginx proxy to port `8929` works without any problems. Just the ssh cloning and connection in general does not work.

I run Ubuntu 18.04 and there is no additional firewall like security groups in AWS.

Did anybody have a similar problem or maybe knows where I could dig deeper?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I solved it, and maybe I can help somebody else:

A friend of mine configured this workaround here in `/etc/ufw/after.rules` https://github.com/chaifeng/ufw-docker

We also disabled port 22 in ufw before because we changed the ssh port on the host.

This led to having port 22 also blocked for the docker-proxy, and opening port 2224 didn't solve anything.

When I used `ufw route allow proto tcp from any to any port 22`
it worked.